# Dictaphone BB10 in QML

Tags: qml, audio-recording, blackberry-10

I need make small app on BB10 using QML, which record and play some voice. I have all needed permision (microphone and store file) and this code:

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
import bb.multimedia 1.0

Page {
    property string dataUrl;

    Container {
        background: Color.create("#001100")
        layout: StackLayout {
        }

        attachedObjects: [
            MediaPlayer {
                id: audioPlayer
                sourceUrl: dataUrl + "/recording.mp4"
            },
            AudioRecorder {
                id: recorder

                outputUrl: dataUrl + "/recording.mp4"
            }
        ]

        Button {
            id: btnRecord
            text: "Record"

            onClicked: {
                recorder.record();
            }
        }

        Button {
            id: btnStop
            text: "Stop Record"

            onClicked: {
                recorder.reset();
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Play Audio"
            onClicked: {
               audioPlayer.play()
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Stop Audio"
            onClicked: {audioPlayer.stop() 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After running I can see all buttons, but recording and/or playing is not work. I dont know what is wrong. I cant see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The problem is your `sourceUrl` is wrong. The best place to store your recording is in your app's [data directory](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/filesystem/) but your QML has no idea where that is.

To solve this you need to expose your app's data path to your QML using C++. You can do this using a property ([more info here](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/)).

Add the following C++ code under where you create your `AbstractPane` object (in my case called `root`). This is normally done in `applicationui.cpp`.

```
root->setProperty("dataUrl", "file://" + QDir::currentPath() + "/data");
```

Now add the `dataUrl` property to your QML and use it for your `sourceUrl`:

```
Page {
    property string dataUrl; 

    Container {
        background: Color.create("#001100")
        layout: StackLayout {
        }

        attachedObjects: [
            MediaPlayer {
                id: audioPlayer
                sourceUrl: dataUrl + "/recording.m4a"
            },
            AudioRecorder {
                id: recorder
                outputUrl: dataUrl + "/recording.m4a"
            }
        ]
        ....
  }
```

Edit: Make sure you call `audioPlayer.reset()` after you've finished recording, this forces the player to reload the recorded audio. If you don't do this your audio playback may be truncated.

Comment: still nothing. Buttons is diplayed but not worked. I debug my app and I saw `com.example.Audio.testDev_ample_Audiodd28f885.315166862    default    9000    WARNING     AudioRecorder::prepare: Error attaching input source. url=audio:default, error=UnsupportedMediaType`

Comment: Are you using the simulator or real device?

Comment: Simulator. Do you think that is a problem?

Comment: Yes, I don't think the simulator supports recording audio via the host's microphone.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you deploy your app to the simulator?

Comment: So, I tried run this on device and I can't becouse I have error " 'Syncing and starting the application' has encountered a problem application is opening." befor running.

Comment: Should I register some class in cpp file?

Comment: Ok. Everything works. I create new project, copy and paste code, and it works. Thaks for your help.